# Проблема с навигацией в приложении

Tags: xcode, swift, mobile-development

В приложении настроена навигация, но когда я настраиваю переход вида

```
let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let initialVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewContr")
self.present(initialVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

viewContr открывается, но навигация отсутствует.

Comment: Что имеется в виду? Что есть в данный момент?

Comment: Спасибо. Я решил проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делай push на навигейшен контроллер, в контексте твоего куска кода это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
if let navigation = self.navigationController {
    navigator.pushViewController(initialVC, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Что-то не получается(((( Я могу задать в initialVC нав контроллер, но тогда будет открываться не тот viewController, но навигация будет.